# Managed file input is removing input values of appended input fields by ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, files

I have a form with checkboxes that are calling ajax callback on checked. This ajax callback is appending another inputs:

```
$form['expertise']['op-cat-'.$op_cat['id']]['op-'.$op['id']]['checked'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => $op['name'],
    '#default_value' => isset($usr['user_scope']['tid'][$op['id']]) ? 1 : 0,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'activit_full_profile_expertise_ajax',
        'wrapper' => 'expertise-div',
    )
);
```

Ajax callback:

```
function activit_full_profile_expertise_ajax($form, &$state) {

    $commands = array();
    $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#expertise-div', render($form['expertise']));
    $commands[] = array('command' => 'reinitializeTooltipster');
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);

}
```

In form is also an another managed file input:

```
$form['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Profilová fotografia <span>(nepovinné)</span>'),
    '#default_value' => isset($usr['picture']->fid) ? $usr['picture']->fid : 0,
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg')),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://user_images/'
);
```

Everything works fine if image field is not used after checkbox. If checkbox is used before image upload, it brings another input fields, but they are not present in `$state['values']` in form validate & submit function (only original checkbox is present). They are not present in validate & submit function called by ajax of this image upload input, therefore they are not present in final validate & submit functions on form submit.

I have another custom ajax callbacks in form, but the appended input values are allways present. Is this a Drupal bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good solution, but now I'm taking values from `$state['input']` instead of `$state['values']`.